# How can i catch json data with multi multidimension?working with high chart

Tags: c#, javascript, json

json data like this

```
[
  {"CH1":-0.026236396484375,"CH2":-0.045433759765625},
  {"CH1":-0.0022396923828125,"CH2":-0.024956572265625}
]
```

js in HTML

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'WeiAshx/highChartm1.ashx',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            options.series[0].data = data.CH1;
            options.series[2].data = data.CH2;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        },
        cache: false
    });
```

Comment: are you handling `data.d` ?

Comment: Did my post below answer your question? Else please clarify :-)

Comment: You thank people by clicking the checkmark icon to the left of their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get two arrays, for CH1 and CH2 resp, iterate over the samples-array and append the CHx-Values accordingly to separate 'series'-arrays.:

```
var ch1 = [], ch2 = [];
for(var i in data) {
 var sample = data[i];
 ch1.push(sample.CH1);
 ch2.push(sample.CH2);
}
```

Than assign the series:

```
options.series[0].data = ch1;
...
```